# How does the cost of EVM memory scale?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, evm

> How does the cost of EVM memory scales?

I wonder how does the cost of EVM memory (not storage) scale?

Indeed, having read other QA's, the cost of memory is not a linear function, but should increase rapidly as more of it is allocated?

Having written the Floyd-Warshall algorithm in Solidity, which allocates an (n x n) matrix of uint's, I see that the gas consumption increases extremly fast. This is the case even for n = 24, where the gas usage is approximately 19085414.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract APSPBenchmark is usingOraclize {

    event OraclizeEvent0(string desc);        
    event OraclizeEvent1(string desc, int[] apsp);

    int constant INF = -1;

    function APSPBenchmark() public payable {}    

    /*
    * Local all-pairs shortest path
    */
    function localAPSP(int[] w) public {

        int[] memory apsp  = allPairsShortestPath(w);

        OraclizeEvent0("local");
        //OraclizeEvent1("local", apsp); // Infinity encoded as -1
    }

    /*
    * All-pairs shortest path
    */
    function allPairsShortestPath(int[] w) private constant returns(int[]) {
        uint i; uint j; uint k;
        uint n = babylonian(w.length);
        int[] memory d = new int[](n * n);

        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                d[i * n +j] = (w[i * n + j] >= 100 ? INF : w[i * n + j]);
            }   
            d[i * n + i] = 0;
        }

        for (k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
            for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                    if (d[i * n + k] == INF || d[k * n + j] == INF) continue;
                    else if (d[i * n + j] == INF) d[i * n + j] = d[i * n + k] + d[k * n + j];
                    else d[i * n + j] = min(d[i * n +j], d[i * n + k] + d[k * n + j]);
                }
            }
        }

        return d;
    }

    /*
    * Minimum of two values
    */
    function min(int a, int b) private constant returns(int)  {
        return a < b ? a : b;
    }    

    /*
    * Babylonian sqrt 
    */
    function babylonian(uint n) private constant returns(uint) {
        uint x = n;
        uint y = 1;
        while (x > y) {
            x = (x + y) / 2;
            y = n / x;
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try defining `INF` with constant: `int constant INF = -1;`  One issue is that the code above is putting `INF` in storage. Every time you use it in the body reading it from storage costs 200 gas.  Declaring it `constant` avoids this.

Comment: Does that fix the huge memory consumption? I can’t try it now.

Comment: As per my answer, memory is not your problem. Changing `INF` to constant will save you up to 600 gas in your inner loop (3 reads of `INF`). Your inner loop is n^3, so for n=24 this saves you up to 600 * 24^3 = 8.3 million gas. That should help.

Comment: Thanks! Still, subtracting 8 million gas from 19085414 (~ 19 million) is ~11 million gas. Isn't this way too much?

Comment: Or is it the all the arithmetic operations and memory lookups that result in such high gas consumption?

Comment: I suggest that you try the above first and then have a look at what's left. This is not your whole contract, so I don't know what else is happening. There are some hand-optimisations you can do in the inner loop, and you can try the Solidity optimiser - it's quite good now - but one thing at a time. If you don't make progress, ask a new question along the lines of "how do I optimise this code", posting the whole contract. The question as you asked it is answered, so you know what to do ;-)

Comment: Tested it now. With your optimization the cost is 10795214 (~10 million) as hypothesized. Indeed, code could always be optimized, but I don't see any "very bad" coding here. I've included the whole contract.

Comment: And with optimization, the cost is 10173951 (~10 million) - thanks, accepted your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68208/discussion-between-benjaminion-and-shuzheng).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The gas cost of memory expansion is defined in the [Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf)
Appendix H, as follows,

[image: Memory Cost Forumula]

G_memory is 3, and `a` is the number of 256-bit words (`int`s) allocated.

For a=24^2 this comes to 3 * 576 + 648 = 2,376.  So it looks like memory cost is not your main problem.

Comment: The above answers your question. However I am also intrigued as to where the gas is going, so I'll do some more digging and post in the comments fi I have any insight.

Comment: The image you put does not show up @benjaminion

Comment: @Avatar - image seems ok in general; may be a local issue. Anyway, it's just equation 222 from the [Yellow Paper](http://yellowpaper.io/).

Comment: Note this the memory cost not the "expansion" cost. See here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/62732/44907 for the distinction

Answer (score 8):

The formula in [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/29905/44907) is actually not the cost of ***expansion***, it is the memory cost.

The cost of expansion is the additional memory cost for the previously untouched memory words.
See [Solidity docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html?#storage-memory-and-the-stack) and quote below from **Appendix H** in the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf).

> Note also that Cmem is the memory cost function (the expansion function being the 
>   difference between the cost before
>   and after). It is a polynomial, with the higher-order coefficient divided and
>   floored, and thus linear up to 724B of memory
>   used, after which it costs substantially more.

(Not enough rep to comment)