# Why does a function which contains 1kb in memory not cost 149,000 gas?

Tags: solidity, gas

I have this useless function which I think allocates 1kb of `memory`.

```
function test_1kb() public returns (string memory) {
    string memory oneKb = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    return oneKb;
}
```

According to [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/29905/85392)  it should cost something like `21,000` (For the base transaction cost) `+ 24,000 + (64,000,000 / 512)`, because my `a` is `8000`.

However, if I test it out on remix, it says that `test_1kb` took about `24314` gas, which is significantly lower than I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `a` is not `8000`

Citing from the post you've included: `G_memory is 3, and a is the number of 256-bit words (ints) allocated.`

Every character in a `string` takes up 2 bytes in memory. Solidity uses 32 bytes (256 bit) memory slots, so one slot can hold exactly 16 characters.

You can even verify that in Remix.
[image]

Now, you string has `1000` characters, that means you're going to need `62,5` (63) memory slots, which is your `a` to plug into that equation.

*Cmem = 3 * 62,5 + ((62,5^2)/512) = 195*